# Is there a way to find out what API's to use for developing a third party app

Tags: reverse-engineering

My company uses an application called TotalHRWorks for time keeping and what not. They have an Android and iOS application; however, there is no Windows Phone application. Since there is an Android and iOS app, I figure that I should be able to create a Windows Phone app; but I don't know where to start with trying to discover maybe their web service or whatever APIs that I could use to make it. I don't know whether this can be done or if it's "legal" to do such things - but it would be really handy to have.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the application's authors?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the very action of reverse engineering 3rd party apps may be breaking your local law.

Comment: The best way to find out if it's legal is to contact the author of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're lucky they'll be communicating with their server over unencrypted HTTP.

If you're mildly lucky they'll be using HTTPS *without* cert pinning.

If you're really unlucky they'll be using HTTPS with cert pinning, or something altogether different.

Regular ol' HTTP is easy to snoop using tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).  If HTTPS is involved you can use *Fiddler* to issue a Root Certificate and get your phone to trust it.  That will allow *Fiddler* to snoop into HTTPS traffic... *unless* the app uses cert-pinning.

If they're not using HTTP-based communication you could look into using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (which is a bit lower level) to try and reverse engineer what's going on.

I got lucky once and managed to reverse engineer a game's API and write my own cheat client.

It was lot's of fun!  So much fun that the dev team eventually emailed me asking me to stop :)

Comment: That was charitable of them.  They didn't lob a lawyer letter at you?

Comment: Maybe I got lucky?  I was never presented with T&Cs or an EULA, so perhaps they had no legal recourse?  Or maybe because I wasn't actually causing them to lose any money they didn't care too much?